# are playerIDs in Game Center utf8

Tags: ios, utf-8, game-center

Is it safe to assume that playerIDs in Game Center are composed entirely of UTF8 characters?  I know in the docs it says not to make any assumptions about the format of this string  as it is subject to change but just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`playerIDs` are ordinary `NSString`s. You should not make assumptions about a particular encoding at this level. But you can get the UTF8-representation with [`UTF8String`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/UTF8String).